# Check if running in Windows Command Prompt vs Cygwin python

Tags: python, command-prompt

Is there a way to check if my python script is running in *Windows Command Prompt*, vs Cygwin? Using `os.name` doesn't work because Cygwin on Windows still returns "nt". I want to check the command prompt's name or type from a shell script so I can differentiate between Command Prompt and Cygwin.

Comment: Maybe the perl version is not exactly the same.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Ops, I mean Python: Cygwin installs its own python executable, so scripts running inside a Cygwin terminal will probably use that. What python executable is used by your scripts running inside a Windows command prompt? If you make them use a different one, possibly a slightly different version, you could check the version and know which environment you are in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know if my python script is running? (using Cygwin or Windows shell)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571333/how-can-i-know-if-my-python-script-is-running-using-cygwin-or-windows-shell)

Comment: My copy of Cygwin uses my Windows' Python. And I don't just want to detect Cygwin, I want to detect specifically Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: My suggestion is to **create** a difference you can detect. Either **make** the script use a slightly different Python version, or create a file before launching the script as abccd suggests, or simply call the script with an additional parameter, e.g. w from cmd and c from cygwin. I can't think of any drawbacks.

Comment: But I want this to work universally. The user shouldn't have to do anything besides run it. If it's just not possible, I'm OK with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
import platform
platform.system()
```

On my system it outputs

`CYGWIN_NT-10.0`

Hope this helps

Comment: actually this works better   `from sys import platform as _platform`  `_platform == "cygwin"`

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem another way, but this works exactly like I wanted.